# How does Matlab compute bicubic interpolation kernel for large kernels?

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I am using Matlab's imresize function to downscale a 3000x2000 image to 120x80 pixel using bicubic interpolation. I stepped through the impementation of Matlab and noticed that a huge number of kernel weights are computed for each output pixel, not just 4x4 as I expected.
Does anyone has an idea how Matlab is computing these kernel weights ?

Comment: For downsampling it probably smooths the image to avoid aliasing.

Answer (score 1):

When downscaling images, the resampling kernel is typical dilated to mitigate [aliasing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aliasing), like Cris said.

The cubic kernel for this factor 25x decimation would be 100x100 in units of input pixels, which is 4x4 in units of *output* pixels. In other words, each output pixel is computed from a patch of 100x100 input pixels. It makes sense considering the large decimation factor that so many pixels need to be aggregated for anti-aliasing.

Kernel weights for standard bicubic resampling are computed from Keys' cubic kernel function, the "W(x)" function [described here on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bicubic_interpolation#Bicubic_convolution_algorithm).